# Android: Squared Diamond Drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to create a drawable to use as a view background that consists of a single squared diamond centered. I've been playing with trying to create a square and rotating it 45 degrees, but it's not really working out as I'd expect. I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions or a working example that they could offer up to help me out. I've tried making this in XML, and recently switched to trying it in Java, like so:

```
public class DiamondView extends Drawable {

private Paint paint;

public DiamondView() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    int height = getBounds().height();
    int width = getBounds().width();

    RectF rect = new RectF( 0.0f, 0.0f, height / 2, height / 2 );

    canvas.rotate( 45 );
    canvas.translate( width / 4, 0 );
    canvas.drawRect( rect, paint );


}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    paint.setColorFilter(cf);
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
}
```

}

Comment: you are quite close, but better solution is to use a standard ShapeDrawable with a custom Shape class: `Drawable d = new ShapeDrawable(yourCustomShapeInstance)`

Comment: @Blackbelt the diamond is just shifted off to the side, and I'm not too sure how exactly I'd center it correctly.

Comment: @pskink Alright, I'll read up on the ShapeDrawable documentation and see if I can get that working. Thanks!

Comment: try translate(width / 2, height / 2 ) and  translate(-width / 2, -height / 2 ) after the rotation

Comment: @PaulRuiz when implementing your draw logic you need just to override Shape#draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) and simply use canvas.rotate(45, xcenter, ycenter) where xcenter and ycenter is your Shape#getWidth()/2 and Shape#getHeight()/2

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure on what's going on now. I'm not seeing the paint at all with 

Drawable d = new ShapeDrawable( new Shape() {
                @Override
                public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
                    canvas.rotate( 45, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2 );
                }
            });
            mIndoorPickerCurrentFloor.setBackgroundDrawable( d );

so I'll just keep playing with it. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: of course you need to set a color and stroke width to your Paint and draw your rect, everything in your `draw()` method

Comment: have you make this drawable ? i also need this and tried many things but did not work

Comment: I did over a year ago, but that was for a previous job and I don't have the source.